# How to change TextAlignment of MetroAnimatedTabItem to center?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using MahApps.Metro for wpf UI. I want to change textalignment of MetroTabItem.

I set HorizontalContentAlignment to center. The below code is not working.

```
        <metroControls:MetroAnimatedTabControl 
            metroControls:TabControlHelper.Underlined="SelectedTabItem" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding TabControlCollection}" SelectedIndex="0">
            <metroControls:MetroAnimatedTabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type metroControls:MetroTabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="metroControls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="34"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                </Style>
```

How to center in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I am solved this question.
I added some code in source. It is perfect working.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type metroControls:MetroTabItem}">
                        <Setter Property="metroControls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="34"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
```